# Где вы храните text plain sql запросы?

Tags: sql, база-данных, pdo, архитектура

В приложении  очень не хочется использовать какие то абстракциии над базой ORM, ActiveRecord. А если писать развесистый sql вперемешку с  кодом,то сильно засоряется кодовая база и т.д , поэтому напрашивается решение  хранить sql код в отдельных *.sql файлах, подгружать их  в вызываемые функции   заменяя плейсхолдерами переданные параметры. Хранимки использовать тоже не хочется. Может быть кто то встречал архитектуры реализующий этот подход, был бы признателен за ссылки на github или идеи. База Postgres. Думаю можно так же абстрагироваться от языка программирования

Comment: Мысли вслух: во-первых, абстракции над базой это всё же хорошо. Во-вторых, если sql засоряет кодовую базу, то, думаю, это намекает на серьёзные проблемы с этим самым sql — в моей практике подавляющее большинство sql-запросов умещались в пару строчек и ничего нигде не засоряло (какая-нибудь сложная статистика-аналитика может быть и большими sql-запросами, но я не думаю, что у вас прям все такие)

Comment: предпочитаю все таки в коде, иначе будет дико не удобно видеть сопоставление переменных кода и полей в запросе

Comment: Массив текстов SQL-запросов - это очень подходящий объект для хранения его в БД. А наличие одного текста запроса, забитого хардкодом, на получение текста запроса по его ID (или всех/некоторых в какую-то внутреннюю коллекцию/массив) можно и пережить... *Хранимки использовать тоже не хочется.* А зря. Вынесение общей логики туда, где она выполняется, более чем разумное решение.

Comment: Селекты хранить во вьюхах, а инсерты/апдейты развесистыми обычно не бывают.

Comment: если речь про пхп, то можно ведь на край инклудить блоки с запросами

Answer (score 1):

Запросы засоряют код в той же мере что и код засоряет запросы :) Храните рядом. Просто заведите отдельный слой под выборку данных этими запросами и они будут преобладать в файлах этого слоя. У Фаулера это называлось [DataMapper](http://design-pattern.ru/patterns/data-mapper.html), во всяких симфони-спрингах это вроде называется DAO (data access object). И все счастливы.